# Is the max of two differentiable functions differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given that $f$ and $g$ are two real functions and both are differentiable, is it true to say that $h=\max{(f,g)} $ is differentiable too?

Thanks

Comment: If you are interested, there is a function [soft max](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/13/soft-maximum/) that approximates the max-function smoothly.

Comment: As a slightly weaker argument -- $max(f,g)$ should at least always be piecewise-differentiable, correct?

Comment: @Brian I'm pretty sure that's true, though it's possibly a separate question to be asked.

Comment: @Matt Separate question [asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247148/is-the-max-of-two-differentiable-functions-piecewise-differentiable)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$. You get $\max(f(x),g(x))=|x|$.

Comment: simplest and easiest approach. wonderful

Answer (score 23):

No, $h(x)=\max(\cos x,\sin x)$ is not differentiable at $x=\dfrac\pi4+k\pi$.

This is because when you switch from $f$ to $g$, the slopes have no reason to be equal.

[image]

Comment: may i ask what software you use to generate this graph?

Comment: @LeeKM: Microsoft Mathematics. It's free and does symbolic computation as well.

Comment: I'll remember this answer if I ever need to draw a pair of lips in a Mathematica plot.

Answer (score 19):

not quite. Observe that: $\text{max}(f,g) = \dfrac{f+g + |f-g|}{2}$, thus if we simply let $f(x) = 2x, g(x) = x$, then we run into problem at $|x|$.

Comment: This is a nice answer; a little more work gives a precise condition for exactly when $\max(f,g)$ will be differentiable.

Comment: The condition is: whenever $f(a) = g(a)$, $f'(a) = g'(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) > g(x)$ Then $F:={\rm max}\{f,g\} =f$ is differentiable at $x$

If $f(x)=g(x)$ and $f(y)< g(y),\ y< x$ and $f(z)> g(z),\ z>x$, then $ \frac{F(y)-F(x) }{y-x}$ goes to $g'(x)$ when $y$ goes to $x$

And $ \frac{F(z)-F(x) }{z-x}$ goes to $f'(x)$ when $z$ goes to $x$. Hence in general $f'(x)\neq g'(x)$ so that it is not differentiable.