# Show space of C1 functions on (0,1) is a Banach lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, vector-lattices

I'm working on the beginning of a book on Banach lattices,  and it wants me to show that $C^1(0,1)$ is a Banach Lattice, with the norm $\|f\|=\|f'\|_\infty+|f(0)|$ and the order $f\le g$ if $f(0)\le f(1)$ and $f'\le g'$ pointwise.

I've shown its a Banach space, but I'm having trouble showing it is a lattice.  In particular,  I am trying to figure out what $f\lor g$ should be.  The naive guess of $\max\{f,g\}$ isn't in the space, as it may not be differentiable, as per [Is the max of two differentiable functions differentiable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246224/is-the-max-of-two-differentiable-functions-differentiable)

The "soft max" function listed has the problem of lack of uniqueness, as its really a family of functions that approaches the max.  Am I missing something?
The question comes from Banach Lattices by Peer Meyer-Nieberg, page 11, exercise 1.1.E3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h'(x) := \max(f'(x), g'(x))$. $h'$ is continuous. Get a primitive function $h$ with $h(0) = \max(f(0), g(0))$. This should do it.

Comment: thanks,  forgot I could max the derivatives and work there!